# How to disable Spree API functionality from existing app

Tags: spree

I have a Rails app developed using the Spree gem.  For security reasons, I'd like to disable all the API functionality - ability to make REST calls, the methods, routes.  I realize that most of the API functionality cannot be invoked without an API token.

What's the best way to 'turn off' the API features?
Best way == least intrusive to existing code base

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this in Spree with the existing setup. I don't want to run a fork of Spree just for this, but this is what I ended up having to do: https://github.com/WebGents/spree/commit/e595b9485f00ec1c89fb6052687f8f6cb2d1b912

Comment: Thanks @mroach That seems pretty clean.  In the end, the two APIs that were giving me security issues were states and countries, as they didn't require an API token.   I ended up adding the API token authentication to them and that seemed to work without negatively affecting the Spree API use cases.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've come up with so far is adding this to my host application's `application.rb` inside the `Application` class:

```
initializer "delete_spree_api_routes", after: "add_routing_paths" do |app|
  app.routes_reloader.paths.delete_if { |path| path =~ /\/spree(-[^\/]+)?\/api\/config\/routes.rb/ }
end
```

What this does is immediately deletes all of the paths from the routes if they were loaded from `routes.rb` provided by the Spree API. It's a bit ugly but it does the job.

**EDIT:** I'd recommend being careful with this as Spree uses its own API in a few cases such as retrieving the list of states for a country (`GET /api/v1/states`)